# How to call an Oracle Form(6i) with user parameters from command line

Tags: oracle, command-line

Is there any way to call an Oracle Form(6i) from command line with **User Parameters** ?

Typing

`ifrun60.exe userid=<uid/pwd> module=<form name>`

in the command line will launch the form, but my form is having some User Parameters to which i need to pass values while launching. Any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing:

```
ifrun60.exe help=Y
```

Tells me what you need is:

```
ifrun60.exe userid=<uid/pwd> module=<form name> [parameters]
```

Answer (score 0):

As my own experience, I omitted "userid" and "module" and I put it in inverse order, like:

ifrun60.exe JOB myusername/mypswd

it works .